# Get height of a scrollable div which has a custom scrollbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, scrollbar, custom-controls

We can use `$('selector')[0].scrollHeight` to get the height of a scrollable div using jquery

I'm not getting the height of div using the above property As I've used custom scrollbar (**mcustomscrollbar**) here.

Is there any way to get the height of a scrollable div in case of **mcustomscrollbar** ?

Here is my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7y6kmto7/1/) to get height of a scrollable div

Please advise me..

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't find any trick to get the height of a scrollable div which has a custom scrollabar

finally i come up with this solution

Just getting the height by doing the summation of the `selector childrens` just like below

```
$(function () {
    $(".content").mCustomScrollbar({
        setHeight: 300
    });
    height = calcualte_height();
    alert($('.content').prop('scrollHeight'));
    alert(height)
});

function calcualte_height() {
    height = 0;
    $('.content').children().each(function() {
        height += $(this).prop('scrollHeight');
    })

    return height;
}
```

Updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7y6kmto7/3/)